# Java 8 map inner static class property in a non static method

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to  get the Java 8 stream equivalent of this old school code.

```
Set<String> studentNames = new HashSet<String>();
for(Student student : students){
           String name =(student.getName());
            studentNames.add(transform(name));
        }
```

Student is inner static class while I need to call the api from non static method. transform is a static method. 
I tried something like this but it doesnt compile.. I get compiler error as static reference cannot be made from non static method...

```
studentNames = Stream.of(students)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(Student::getName)
                .map(Transformer::transform)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Use `students.stream()` instead of `Stream.of(students)`. Whether `Student` is a nested class or not, is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: I get compiler error as static reference cannot be made from non static method.

Comment: This did the trick- students.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(student->student.getName())
                .map(Transformer::transform)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your problem is here `Transformer::transform`, you need an actual instance of `transformer` to make this work.

```
Transformer t = new Transformer(...);

list.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(Student::getName)
            .map(t::transform)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Also it looks like `Transformer` is just a `Function<String, String>` btw.

Comment: The loop code does not suggest that a `Transformer` instance is needed. Ironically, you have fixed [the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46314540/java-8-map-inner-static-class-property-in-a-non-static-method#comment79594671_46314540) in your code without noticing it.

Comment: yes- Transformer is another static class used to transform the names. I think that part is fine.. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

As Holger said in his comment, your problem is caused by calling `Stream.of(students)`. If you look at `of`'s signature, you'll see that it expects either a single element or an **array** of elements. Hence, if you give it a **collection**, you'll get a stream of collections, not of the collection's elements:

```
Stream<String>       s1 = Stream.of("hello");
Stream<String>       s2 = Stream.of("hello", "world");
Stream<String>       s3 = Stream.of(new String[] {"hello", "world"});
Stream<List<String>> s4 = Stream.of(Arrays.asList("hello", "world"));
Stream<String>       s5 = Arrays.asList("hello", "world").stream();
```